# Apex - Update Account of Contact

Tags: apex

I am new to Salesforce. Trying to add an existing account to an existing contact. The code does not throw error but does not work.

```
try{
Contact cnt = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name, Account.Id, FirstName, LastName, Name From Contact where FirstName = 'Sal' and LastName = 'Sands'];
Account acct = [select Name, Id From Account where Name = 'Universal Mobile Solutions'];

System.debug(cnt.Account.Id);
System.debug(cnt.Account.Name);

If(cnt.Account == null){
    cnt.Account = new Account();
    cnt.Account = acct;

    update cnt.Account;
}

System.debug(cnt.Account.Id);
System.debug(cnt.Account.Name);
}

catch(DMLException e){
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Fixed the code and it works now. Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
Contact cnt = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name, Account.Id, FirstName, LastName, Name From Contact where FirstName = 'Sal' and LastName = 'Sands'];
Account acct = [select ID From Account where Name = 'Universal Mobile Solutions'];

ID acctId = acct.ID;

System.debug(cnt.AccountId);

If(cnt.Account == null){
    cnt.AccountId = acctId;

    update cnt;
}

System.debug(cnt.AccountId);
}

catch(DMLException e){
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
     List<Account> aclist=[select id,name from account where Name = 'Universal Mobile Solutions'];
   list<contact> clist=[select id,name,accountid from contact where 
      FirstName = 'Sal' and LastName = 'Sands'];
       List<contact> clist1=new List<contact>();
       for(account ac:aclist){
            for(contact c:clist){
                if(c.accountid!=null){
                    c.Accountid=ac.id;
                       clist1.add(c);
                   }
             }
         }  if(!clist1.isEmpty()){
       update clist1;
   }
```